# Escaping the separator in str_getcsv

Tags: php

`str_getcsv("test\\.a.b", ".", "'", "\\");`

I would expect the above to equal `["test.a", "b"]`, however it equals `["test\", "a", "b"]`. Am I misunderstanding the purpose or usage of the `$escape` argument? I want to escape the separator such that the result is the former array.

Comment: Well, to be honest, if myself understood your piece of code correctly, than getting a result of `["test\", "a", "b"]` is what I would refer to as `working properly`. Mainly because it fulfills the request you made, so every time it parses a `.` (dot). It then seperates the values.

Comment: So, what does the `$escape` argument do, and how do I escape the first period?

Comment: Why do you post the same question with multiple Accounts?

Comment: What's with the double posting? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71018262/escaping-the-separator-in-str-get-csv

Comment: @brombeer That's very confusing, I have nothing to do with them haha

Comment: Why do you have many [unclosed questions](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7473854/cb7?tab=questions) and no comment to answers?

Comment: @cb7 If the answer from Syscall helped you you should accept and upvote the answer. If it didn't help then ask for further help in comments of his post.

Answer (score 1):

You could use the "enclosure" char to enclose a separator char:

```
var_dump(str_getcsv("'test.a'.b", ".", "'", "\\"));
```

Output:

```
array(2) {
  [0]=>
  string(6) "test.a"
  [1]=>
  string(1) "b"
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure single quotes are valid in CSV? Should be `\"`

Comment: Single or double quotes are allowed.